# Eclipse Kepler Maven Archetype Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, maven-archetype

On eclipse, I tried creating a project using maven-archetype-webapp, though the directory structure was correct, build plugins were messed up. After executing mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0, even the project structure got messed.

On the other hand, i tried creating a dynamic web project and converted it to a maven project. but, that didnt fix the directory structure.

I am trying to create a simple maven web project with war plugin and 
src -> main -> java, webapp, resources
    -> test -> java, resources

directory stucture. Can anyone pls suggest a proper way to do this?

When i tried changing the structure manually, i kept getting cannot nest error.

Answer (score 0):

file > new maven project > select archetype from list > org.apache.maven.archetype:maven-archetype-webapp

and don't use `eclipse:eclipse` in goal you can live nicely without it